# Changing Gmail image next to logo

Tags: gmail, google-workspace-for-business, g-suite-administrator

A customer I inherited has uses GMAIL.  When they log in to gmail, at the top right of the screen to the left of their image there is an image representative of their business (seen in the below image as ?????)

[image: Gmail top screen image]

How can that image be changed?

Comment: Looks like you need a G Suite account (and be an administrator of such organization to change it. See here: https://support.google.com/a/answer/96474?hl=en

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's the G Suite version of Gmail (previously known as Google Apps).

Sign in to the Admin Console at https://admin.google.com/ – you will need a privileged account within the G Suite organization – then go to the "Account Settings" section. You'll be able to upload a new logo there.

(The new logo might take a few minutes to actually begin showing everywhere.)

[image: Account settings button]
[image: Logo section]